# C++ help with getline function with ifstream

Tags: c++, ifstream, getline

So I am writing a program that deals with reading in and writing out to a file. I use the getline() function because some of the lines in the text file may contain multiple elements. I've never had a problem with getline until now. Here's what I got.

The text file looks like this:

```
  John Smith                       // Client name
  1234 Hollow Lane, Chicago, IL    // Address
  123-45-6789                      // SSN
  Walmart                          // Employer
  58000                            // Income
  2                                // Number of accounts the client has
  1111                             // Account Number
  2222                             // Account Number
```

And the code like this:

```
ifstream inFile("ClientInfo.txt");
if(inFile.fail())
{
    cout << "Problem opening file.";
}
else
{
    string name, address, ssn, employer;
    double income;
    int numOfAccount;

    getline(inFile, name);
    getline(inFile, address);
    // I'll stop here because I know this is where it fails.
```

When I debugged this code, I found that name == "John", instead of name == "John Smith", and Address == "Smith" and so on. Am I doing something wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This program compiles and works as expected for me. Are you sure you didn't previously have something like `cin >> name; cin >> address;` that you replaced with `getline` and just forget to save the source file and/or recompile the program before testing again?

Comment: WFM (works for me). I pasted your code into a source file, added various includes and `std::` prefixes, pasted the text into a `ClientInfo.txt` file (removing // comments), added a line printing `name` to `std::cout`, compiled and ran. `name` was `John Smith` for me.

Comment: Why do you use the c-style `getline` instead of `istream::getline`?

Comment: @dmckee He's using `std::getline`. He's clearly got a `using namespace std;` somewhere above as evidenced by the use of raw `ifstream` and `string` without namespace qualifiers. This is correct, by the way. Note that `std::getline` can support reading into a `std::string`, but `istream::getline` will only read into a `char*`.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Are you sure about the contents of your text file?

Comment: @dmckee - istream::getline uses `char *` and does not support `std::string`.  The free function `getline` supports `std::string` so he is doing the right thing.

Comment: Ah. This would be "Chapter 11: in which dmckee's ignorance is finally discovered".

Comment: Yea I don't know, I've spent the last hour trying to figure it out, I probably will just write it over. I've compiled everything and saved everything. So Im stumped.

Comment: Okay I have it working but I ran into another problem, say I have two clients in the file, it reads the first one fine but before it gets the name of the second client, getline reads in a "". Why does it do that. If it isn't clear let me know.

Comment: @poorStudent: if this problem is solved, mark an answer.  If you have an additional question, make a new question.

Answer (score 2):

The code you show should work on that file.  So something must be different than you think.  The most likely culprits are:

1. The file actually has a newline where you think it only has a space
2. The code uses `inFile >> name` where you think it uses `getline(inFile,name)`

Perhaps you changed something and forgot to save or recompile or you are reading a a different file than you think.

By the way, from your variable declarations it looks like you may be planning to mix `getline()` calls with extraction operator calls like `inFile >> income`.  Mixing these requires care because the extraction operator leaves behind trailing whitespace that `getline()` might then read.  There's more information near the bottom of [this](http://www.arachnoid.com/cpptutor/student2.html).